# "fetch is not defined" on vuepress build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuepress

I am trying to build a static site with vuepress. I have a vue component that is used that uses the javascript `fetch` library. It looks like this:

```
<template>
<div>
    <p> {{totalVuePackages}} </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "get-request",
  data() {
    return {
      totalVuePackages: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => (this.totalVuePackages = data.total));
  }
};
</script>
```

If I use `vuepress dev` it works perfectly with no errors. However, when I use `vuepress build` I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I'm new to vue and javascript, but I was under the assumption that `fetch` is a built-in javascript method that runs on the clientside.

Comment: If you are trying to use the built-in `fetch` - why are you including another `fetch` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build process is done in node environment instead of browser, that's why fetch is not defined.

vuepress calls `created` hook to produce static html files.
if you want to call fetch only on client side, you should call it on `mounted` hook instead which will not be called in build process.